# React-Native <Navigator/> : How do I control it from the class that instantiated it

Tags: react-native, navigator

I have a  instantiated in my index.ios.js file like this:

```
render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{
          component: test,
          navigationBar: <NavigationBar title="home" />
        }}/>
    );
}
```

From this same file I have a function that I would like to be able to trigger an action on the navigator e.g.

```
resetStack(){
  // navigator.popToTop();
}
```

How do I achieve this? I thought I had to use something called refs and have tried adding a reference as follows:

```
render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        ref="ref1"
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{
          component: test,
          navigationBar: <NavigationBar title="home" />
        }}/>
    );
}
```

then calling this with:
    resetStack(){
      // navigator.popToTop();
      ref1.popToTop();
    }

But this results in an error:
Can't find variable ref1

How do I achieve this? How do I trigger methods in child components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue. I was quite close with the above code but neglected to add the this.refs.referenceName to the call, the final code was:

```
render() {
    return(
      <Navigator
        ref="ref1"
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{
          component: test,
          navigationBar: <NavigationBar title="home" />
        }}/>
    );
}
```

and call this with:

```
resetStack(){
  // navigator.popToTop();
  this.refs.ref1.popToTop();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The `renderScene` method is invoked with the route and the navigator context, which allows you to pass the navigator into the scene component:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
  return <ExampleScene navigator={navigator} />;
}
```

From within ExampleScene, you now can call `this.props.navigator.popToTop()`.

---

Alternatively, call `Navigator.getContext(this)` from a component within a navigator:

```
Navigator.getContext(this).popToTop();
```

---

The documentation is available here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigation-context

Comment: Thanks @ide I think I maybe didn't explain myself properly. I wanted to be able to trigger functions that reside in the child classes from the parent class. I have managed to get references working now. I realise where I was going wrong. Thank you. Keep up the good work. Loving React Native!